# how to fetch api just onc in build time in a SSR page in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I tried to include getStaticProps + getInitialProps simultaneously but nextjs does not allow this.

Why i need this?

because an api data fetch needs to be done just once at build-time and be shared after that.
This api returns a json file that will be used to create menu categories.
Now I have created a json file and after analyzing bundles i saw that each page of my application has this json file and the size of common chunk had increased.
How can i solve this problem? what is the best pattern to implement menu category header with lots of categories?